# C++ IDispatch : impossible to release

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm trying to migrate a program to another mingw version, in order to compile on another 32 bits computer. This program use the IDispatch interface, and compiles fine on my computer, but when trying with the orther mingw version, I get this error :

'struct IDispatch' has no member named 'Release'

Which is very wierd, because it IDispatch implements IUknown which has this method.

Is there a compilation option I have missed or something ?

Here is part of my code (actually, a part of the disphelper project which is used by the code):

```
class CDhComPtr
{
public:
CDhComPtr() throw() : m_pInterface (NULL) {}

CDhComPtr(T* pInterface) throw() : m_pInterface (pInterface)
{
    if (m_pInterface) m_pInterface->AddRef();
}

CDhComPtr(const CDhComPtr& original) throw() : m_pInterface (original.m_pInterface)
{
    if (m_pInterface) m_pInterface->AddRef();
}

~CDhComPtr() throw()
{
    Dispose();
}

void Dispose() throw()
{
    if (m_pInterface)
    {
        m_pInterface->Release();
        m_pInterface = NULL;
    }
}

T* Detach() throw()
{
    T* temp = m_pInterface;
    m_pInterface = NULL;
    return temp;
}

T** operator&() throw()
{
    Dispose();
        return &m_pInterface;
}

CDhComPtr& operator=(T* pInterface) throw()
{
    if (m_pInterface != pInterface)
    {
        T* pOldInterface = m_pInterface;
        m_pInterface = pInterface;
        if (m_pInterface)  m_pInterface->AddRef();
        if (pOldInterface) pOldInterface->Release();
    }

    return *this;
}


private:
    T* m_pInterface;
};

typedef CDhComPtr<IDispatch>    CDispPtr;
typedef CDhComPtr<IEnumVARIANT> CEnumPtr;
typedef CDhComPtr<IUnknown>     CUnknownPtr;
```

Sorry if my english is bad, I'm from france.

This version of Mingw implements IDispatch like this :

```
#define INTERFACE IDispatch
DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IDispatch,IUnknown)
{
    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(THIS_ REFIID,PVOID*) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,AddRef)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD_(ULONG,Release)(THIS) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetTypeInfoCount)(THIS_ UINT*) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetTypeInfo)(THIS_ UINT,LCID,LPTYPEINFO*) PURE;
    STDMETHOD(GetIDsOfNames)(THIS_ REFIID,LPOLESTR*,UINT,LCID,DISPID*)PURE;
    STDMETHOD(Invoke)(THIS_ DISPID,REFIID,LCID,WORD,DISPPARAMS*,VARIANT*,EXCEPINFO*,UINT*) PURE;
};
#undef INTERFACE
```

Comment: we need to see your declaration of IDispatch and IUnknown

Comment: IDispatch is implemented in this version of Mingw, so there is no way I can change its implementation, I don't have the rights. (Added in first post)